# How to change a variable type in TypeScript without rewriting the variable?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a way to help the TS compiler by specifying a more specific variable type.

I'm looping over an array of elements that can be anything.

```
map(airtableRecord?.fields, (fieldValue: any | any[], fieldName: string) => {}
```

*N.B: the `any | any[]` could be written as `any`, but I prefer `any | any[]` because it helps me not forget that it can also be an array, it's more a documentation tip.*

Then, I perform some checks on the `fieldValue` variable, and I know it can then only be a subset of types.

```
if (fieldSchema?.relationship) {} // From now on, I know "fieldValue" MUST BE an array of "things"
```

At this point, I currently write the following:

```
fieldValue = fieldValue as string[] | AirtableRecord[];
```

This is a useless operation, but it's the only way I could think of to tell the TS compiler that  `fieldValue` type is different from now on.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use [a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) - if you have `if (isMyType(data))` then within the body of the `if`` the `data` variable will be treated as `MyType`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMicjAPbkBcyAzmFKAOYDchAvoYTAK4gJhg5EMmC0M2PAAoAHjTgh0ASmQ0Zo2miy4CxUlAhgeUEQCIK5U6JEy2nQgmH1kcKFHmKA2gF1kAXmRPfHYAGmR8CxpTAAsIABs4y1DwgCNXKIB3cig4gBNTdm82LgooZClHEGdgSABbZHIYFzcVIlJRJqkxCR0uuqVWvXaSStpyOIgAOkSmPohayYslIeROdiA)

Comment: Interesting. I feel like it's more complicated to read/understand/maintain than my little hack though (for my particular piece of code). Doesn't feel worth the trouble, in my case.